# Trouble in sql prepared statment in java

Tags: java, sql

I have an error in my sql syntax when trying to set a value in my table (events) using a where clause with a prepared statement 
this is the code `

```
public void setEventParticipants(int id, String eventParticipants)
    {

            try {
            String req1="insert into events (eventParticipants) values(?) where (eventId)=?";
            PreparedStatement pre = c.prepareStatement(req1);
            pre.setString(1, eventParticipants);
            pre.setInt(2, id);
            pre.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EventService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }`
```

I got this error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (eventId)=7' at line 1
thanks for your help

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to run an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
insert into events (eventParticipants) values(?) where (eventId)=?
```

to This

```
UPDATE events SET eventParticipants = ? WHERE eventId = ?
```

If you do an insert statement, it should be populating your table

Comment: thanks i feel stupid for using insert instead of update but thanks  . i ll set as answer as soon as i can

Comment: If if does help you, don't forget to accept, as someone else could have the same problem as you :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
try with 
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
or
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (&value1, &value2, &value3, ...);

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong. Please read MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) about the INSERT statement and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) about the UPDATE, and how they should be used, with examples. INSERT cannot be used to update existing row.

I suspect that the right statement would be

```
update events set eventParticipants = ? where eventId = ?
```

but this depends on what are you trying to achieve.